# mysql update duplicate records based on data from a associated table

Tags: mysql

Ok, I am going to attempt to ask this question again. My last post got closed cause it wasn't a more elaborate question so I will try to be more specific.

A user receives messages and the status is marked `unread` or `read` based on whether they clicked hat they've read the message or not.

Well there have been users that said they recieved duplicate messages. The problem is the record that keeps track of the message is in a second table. so the 2 tables look like this

subject_table

```
id     user_id     message_id        created        status
1      34          81                03/11/12       read
2      34          82                06/15/12       unread
3      34          83                06/16/12       unread
4      35          84                07/10/12       read
5      35          85                07/12/12       unread
6      35          86                07/14/12       unread
7      35          87                07/14/12       unread
8      24          88                08/09/12       read
```

message_table

```
id     message     
81     'welcome'         
82     'welcome'  //duplicate for user 34, associated table needs to be set to read      
83     'welcome'  //duplicate for user 34, this record needs to be set to read        
84     'welcome'          
85     'welcome'
86     'welcome'
87     'pretty cool' //not a duplicate for user 35
88     'welcome'  // not a duplicate for user 24
```

what makes this question different from the first is there is a associated table here. I need to go through each table and only update tables that have duplicate messages. see record 87 in message_table? well there is no duplicate so that is ignored.

So my question is how do I update table 1 based on duplication with the associated table.

## [EDIT]

When I mean duplicate, I mean all users with a associated message with the same message value.
so looking at the example. `user_id` 34 has 3 records. if we look up the `message_id` for each record, we will find the same message 'welcome' repeated 3 times. this is a duplicate record for `user_id` 34

### The following is a fail

```
UPDATE subject_table
SET `status` = 'read'
WHERE
    user_id IN (
        SELECT
            s.user_id
        FROM
            subject_table s
        INNER JOIN messages m ON m.id = s.message_id
        WHERE
            m.message LIKE '%welcome%'
        GROUP BY
            s.user_id
        HAVING
            count(s.user_id) > 1);
```

What I am trying to do here is in my subquery, get the list of ids that have multiple duplicate records then update the associated record status to read.
But the issue I get with this is the following error

```
Error : You can't specify target table 'subject_table' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what constitutes a duplicate here? Is it same user, same message? That would mean id's 1,2,3 from subject_table are duplicates of one another. Or should the created date be factored in too? In that case I don't see any duplicates in this same, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for a message to be duplicate, all of `user_id`, `message` and `created` must be  the same, the following statement should do it:

```
UPDATE subject_table, message_table
SET    subject_table.status = <status>
WHERE  subject_table.message_id = message_table.id
AND    subject_table.user_id = <user-id>
AND    message_table.message = <message>
AND    subject_table.created = <created>
```

(where `<user_id>`, `<message>` and `<created>` are placeholders for actual values for the respective columns and `<status>` is the value for the new status)

This is called the multi-table UPDATE syntax and is described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I want it to apply to all users so I wouldn't need the user_id in the criteria. nor would I need the createdd. I would need for message to be a LIKE and I have to have some way to tell whether there is duplicate copies of the message or not. if it occurs only once, its ignored. user_id 24 in my example would get ignored. I think every user has this message. so I want to ignore the ones that only have one and apply to ones that have duplicates

Comment: So why didn't you put this information in your question then? Another question is, why did you allow these duplicates to be entered into your database in the first place?

Comment: lol, it was a bug. I didn't allow it but I am trying to fix it. put it that way. and my apologizes. I will update my information